# D3 Chart does not redraw on new data

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg, redraw

Using react I draw a D3 scatter chart. When I try to add new lines on the chart through the `svg` i initialize at the start, it works i.e. when using the button rendered in the svg and the onlick function.

When I try to do this using the parent's props, the function to add the lines gets triggered but the lines are not added. I have read other posts about using `enter()` but this does not work. What I think is wrong is the way I setup the div structure to mount the original SVG, since I have a div with class `chart-container` and inside it a div with id `chart`, which I add the SVG inside. Does anyone thing the way I am selecting the `svg` when adding the lines is wrong? I do not understand why the lines are not rendered on the D3 chart.

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

import './Chart.css';

const Chart = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    drawChart(props.data)
  }, [props.columnType]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (showLines) {
      addLines(props.data)
      return
    } else {
      removeLines()
    }
  }, [props.showLines]);

  const addLines = (data) => {
      const x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
      const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
      const parsedData = parseData(data, columnType);

      parsedData.forEach((dataSet, index) => {
        const { points } = dataSet;
        const line = d3.line()
          .x((d) => x(d.x))
          .y((d) => y(d.yhat));
        // If I use this selection, I cannot add the lines
        d3.select("svg").enter().append("path")
          .datum(points)
          .attr("class", `line`)
          .attr("d", line);
      });
  }

  const drawChart = (data) => {
    ..... // Other code not added (related to configuring the graph)
    // If I use this SVG I can add the lines
    const svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("id", "chart-svg")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    ..... // other code not added (related to rendering the points using the data)

  }

  return (
    <div className="chart-container">
      <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you can only use `enter` with selection that had data bound to it with `data`

Comment: carefully have a look at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 and make sure you understand every single bit there

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I need to reset the x and y ranges again, as it was rendering the lines off screen.